# Complex list slice/index in python

Tags: python, list, slice

I have a list that looks like this:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

I'd like to generate a filtered list that looks like this:

```
filtered_lst = [2, 6, 7, 9, 10, 13]
```

Does Python provide a convention for custom slicing. Something such as:

```
lst[1, 5, 6, 8, 9, 12] # slice a list by index
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`operator.itemgetter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

itemgetter(1, 5, 6, 8, 9, 12)(lst)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
>>> itemgetter(1, 5, 6, 8, 9, 12)(lst)
(2, 6, 7, 9, 10, 13)
```

This returns a tuple; cast to a list with `list(itemgetter(...)(lst))` if a that is a requirement.

Note that this is the equivalent of a slice expression (`lst[start:stop]`) with a set of indices instead of a range; it can not be used as a left-hand-side slice assignment (`lst[start:stop] = some_iterable`).

Comment: With a slice you can modify the underlying list. Can you do that with itemgetter?

Comment: \*mumble mumble\* "one way to do it" \*mumble mumble mumble\* ;)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You cannot use it as a left-hand assignment target, no.

Comment: Since the question explicitly mentions slicing, perhaps you should mention left-hand assignment in the answer

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It *is* a slice, just not a slice *assignment*.

Comment: It is not a Python `slice`. It is a generic slice.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I am covering [simple slicing](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#slicings) here, as a expression primary, explicitly excluding [slice assignment](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements). Not sure what you are talking about now, in any case. :-)

Comment: I mean that `slice` is a precise and specific term in Python. As defined by the link in your previous comment. And `itemgetter` is not a Python `splice`. Although it has a very strong functionality overlap. Anyway, your update is good!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: 'slice' could also mean an extended slice (not supported by python the `list` type), which *does* allow for a `[index1, index2, .., indexn]` notation. The *result* of a slice expression is a new list, and that's what I think the OP is after. :-) The *other* use of a slice is as an assignment target, which is what I think you mean, and that is very much out of scope here. Just getting our terminology sorted out here, I think! :-)

Comment: Just for the record: `a[index1, index2, .., indexn]` is disambiguated in the docs to be a subscription, *not* a slicing.

Comment: @WolframH: kinda, sorta; extended slicing basically results in `__getitem__` being called with one argument in all cases, and that can be a list of slice objects. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Numpy arrays have this kind of slicing syntax:

```
In [45]: import numpy as np

In [46]: lst = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13])

In [47]: lst[[1, 5, 6, 8, 9, 12]]
Out[47]: array([ 2,  6,  7,  9, 10, 13])
```

Answer (score 2):

It's easily and straightforwardly done using a list comprehension.

```
lst = range(1, 14)
indices = [1, 5, 6, 8, 9, 12]
filtered_lst = [lst[i] for i in indices]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the `operator.itemgetter()` method that Martijn Pieters has suggested, but here's another way (for completeness)

```
In [23]: lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

In [24]: indices = set([1, 5, 6, 8, 9, 12])

In [25]: [n for i,n in enumerate(lst) if i in indices]
Out[25]: [2, 6, 7, 9, 10, 13]
```

Answer (score 0):

A Python slice allows you to make the slice the target of an assignment. And the Python slicing syntax does not allow for slices with irregular patterns of indices. So, if you want to make your "custom" slice the target of an assignment, that's not possible with Python slice syntax.

If your requirements are met by taking a copy of the specified elements, then `operator.itemgetter()` meets your needs. If you need slice assignment, then numpy slices are a good option.