# Slices with several intervals?

Tags: python

I have a file where I want to extract columns 2, 3, 4, 5 and column -4. These columns are not adjacent.

For reasons of code neatness I'd like to do something like

`values = line.split()[columns_to_extract]`

instead of

`values_part_one = line.split()[columns_to_extract_one]
values_part_two = line.split()[columns_to_extract_two]`

Therefore I'd like to make a slice that contains the positions 2, 3, 4, 5 and -4 to be able to extract the values in one line. Is this possible?

If not, are there any other neat oneliners that could do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Complex list slice/index in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114621/complex-list-slice-index-in-python)

Comment: It is very similar, but didn't show up in any search. Its title is too abstract and nondescriptive- few people looking for a solution to this problem are going to search for 'complex' slices I'd wager.

Comment: It was the first thing that came to *my* mind, but then we are all unique. I find that Google works better than SO's own search -- for this type of question the top Google hits will be on SO anyway.

Comment: I too voted to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it possible to make a slice to do that?  No.

However, all is not lost!  You *can* use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
getter = operator.itemgetter(2, 3, 4, 5, -4)
```

example:

```
>>> import operator
>>> getter = operator.itemgetter(2, 3, 4, 5, -4)
>>> getter(range(50))  # Note, returns a `tuple`
(2, 3, 4, 5, 46)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
parts = line.split()
values_part_one = [parts[i] for i in columns_to_extract_one]
values_part_two = [parts[i] for i in columns_to_extract_two]
```

or, as @mgilson points out, you could use `operator.itemgetter` to get tuples:

```
import operator
extract_one = operator.itemgetter(*columns_to_extract_one) # or list explicitly
extract_two = operator.itemgetter(*columns_to_extract_two) # if using fixed cols

parts = line.split()
values_part_one = extract_one(parts)
values_part_Two = extract_two(parts)
```

Note that both of these will fail with `IndexError` if the thing you are trying to grab from isn't large enough to contain all of the specified indices.